# How to skip the ? in prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Here is my PostgreSQL raw query which is working fine.

```
    select * from employee where to_json(array( select jsonb_array_elements(employeeids) ->> 'id'))::
jsonb?|array['22', '17', '23', '24'] AND empname =?;
```

but when I run the java code it's excepting me to give two values, but the first? is part of the query, for which I need not supply any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping the first question mark by two question marks `??`.

Comment: Yeap, https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/statement.html

Comment: Thanks, Joop Eggen & pleft